# In WPF, when i press button, another event button is executed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, focus

I've got a problem on my application who is developped in C# WPF (framework 4.6.1).

I use a touch screen and for a push event, i use the StylusButtonUp or StylusButtonDown event.

Sometimes, when i push on one button, the event of another button is executed.

I try to create a ghost button and give the focus at the end of each event (with the Focus() method), but it doesn't work.

There is a sample of the xaml code:

```
        <TextBlock x:Name="TB_AcessManagment" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Franklin Gothic Medium" FontSize="16" Margin="404.5,136.665,279.5,590.5" TextAlignment="Center" StylusButtonUp="BP_AccessManagment_StylusButtonUp" Text="Gestion Accès"/>
        <Button x:Name="BP_SSL100Setting" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="73,313,0,0" Style="{DynamicResource SonimatButtonImageStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="63" Height="63" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="{x:Null}" Focusable="False" RenderTransformOrigin="1.254,1.349" StylusButtonUp="BP_SSL100Setting_StylusButtonUp">
            <Button.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Button.RenderTransform>
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/SNT_ComponentLibrary;component/Image/d├®coupe-01.png"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
        <TextBlock x:Name="TB_SSL100Setting" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Franklin Gothic Medium" FontSize="16" Margin="44.5,376,639.5,372" TextAlignment="Center" Text="Découpe" StylusButtonUp="BP_SSL100Setting_StylusButtonUp"/>
        <Button x:Name="BP_SSL200Setting" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="193,313,0,0" Style="{DynamicResource SonimatButtonImageStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="63" Height="63" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="{x:Null}" Focusable="False" RenderTransformOrigin="1.254,1.349" StylusButtonUp="BP_SSL200Setting_StylusButtonUp">
            <Button.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Button.RenderTransform>
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/SNT_ComponentLibrary;component/Image/transitique-01-01.png"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
        <TextBlock x:Name="TB_SSL200Setting" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Franklin Gothic Medium" FontSize="16" Margin="164.5,376,519.5,352.163" TextAlignment="Center" StylusButtonUp="BP_SSL200Setting_StylusButtonUp" Text="Transitique"/>
        <Button x:Name="BP_SSL201Setting" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="433,313,0,0" Style="{DynamicResource SonimatButtonImageStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="63" Height="63" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="{x:Null}" Focusable="False" RenderTransformOrigin="1.254,1.349" StylusButtonUp="BP_SSL201Setting_StylusButtonUp">
            <Button.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Button.RenderTransform>
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/SNT_ComponentLibrary;component/Image/transitique-01-01.png"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
        <TextBlock x:Name="TB_SSL201Setting" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Franklin Gothic Medium" FontSize="16" Margin="404.5,376,279.5,349.837" TextAlignment="Center" StylusButtonUp="BP_SSL201Setting_StylusButtonUp" Text="Sortie"/>
        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="338.5" Margin="11.5,419.5,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="784" Fill="#FF9B9B9B"/>
        <Button x:Name="BP_SSL400Setting" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="313,313,0,0" Style="{DynamicResource SonimatButtonImageStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="63" Height="63" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="{x:Null}" Focusable="False" RenderTransformOrigin="1.254,1.349" StylusButtonUp="BP_SSL400Setting_StylusButtonUp">
            <Button.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Button.RenderTransform>
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/SNT_ComponentLibrary;component/Image/ultrasons-01-01-01.png"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
```

Someone has got the same problem ? How can i solve it ?

Thanks for all answer.

Comment: can you post code snippets of the code and xaml?

Comment: You should post you XAML code. It is likely you tried to copy buttons in the xaml code, bot forgot to change the event handler names.

Comment: I've add the xaml code and as you can see, the event handler name is different, I don't understand what can happened.